# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make the bot run faster?

Tags: python, discord.py

I noticed that whenever a command is triggered, the bot usually takes a couple of seconds to respond. Is there any way I can increase the overall speed of the bot? I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code if it helps:

```
import discord
import os
import random
import praw
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import time


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


sec_triggers = ['just a sec', 'Just a sec', 'just a second', 'Just a second', 'one sec', 'one second', 'One sec', 'One second']
monke_triggers = ['monke', 'Monke', 'Monkey', 'monkey']
hello_triggers = ['hello there', 'Hello there', 'hello There', 'Hello There']
f_triggers = ['f in the chat', 'F in the chat', 'f in the Chat', 'F in the Chat']
colors = [0xff0000, 0xff3300, 0xff6600, 0xff9900, 0xffcc00, 0xffff00, 0xccff00, 0x99ff00, 0x66ff00, 0x33ff00, 0x00ff00, 0x00ff33, 0x00ff66, 0x00ff99, 0x00ffcc, 0x00ffff, 0x00ccff, 0x0099ff, 0x0066ff, 0x0033ff, 0x0000ff, 0x3300ff, 0x6600ff, 0x9900ff, 0xcc00ff, 0xff00ff, 0xff00cc, 0xff0099, 0xff0066, 0xff0033]
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="you, Wazowski. Always Watching. Always."))



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
   return
  
  msg = message.content
  
  if any(word in msg for word in monke_triggers):
   await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Reject Humanity, Return to Monke.jpg'))
  
  if any(word in msg for word in sec_triggers):
   time. sleep(1)
   await message.channel.send("It's been one second")
  
  if any(word in msg for word in hello_triggers):
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('General_Kenobi.gif'))
  
  if any(word in msg for word in f_triggers):
    mention = message.author.name
    await message.channel.send(f"{mention} had paid their respects.")

  if message.content.lower() == 'f' or message.content.lower() == 'F':
    mention = message.author.name
    await message.channel.send(f"{mention} had paid their respects.")
  
  await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command()
async def catjam(ctx, *, text):
    message = f"{text}"
    new_message = ""
    for char in message:
      new_message += f"<a:catjam:800476635655962644>{char}"
    new_message += "<a:catjam:800476635655962644>"
    await ctx.send(new_message)
    await ctx.message.delete()

@client.command()
async def echo(ctx, *, text):
  await ctx.send(f"{text}")
  await ctx.message.delete()

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, text):
    reason = f"{text}"
    mention = ctx.message.author.name
    pfp = member.avatar_url
    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{member} has been kicked.", color = random.choice(colors))
    em.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason)
    em.add_field(name="Responsible User:", value=mention)
    em.set_thumbnail(url=(pfp))
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, text):
    reason = f"{text}"
    mention = ctx.message.author.name
    pfp = member.avatar_url
    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{member} has been banned.", description= f"__Reason:__ {reason} __Responsible moderator:__ {mention}", color = random.choice(colors))
    em.set_thumbnail(url=(pfp))
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)


@client.command()
async def comic(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("comic")
    all_subs = []
    hot = subreddit.hot(limit = 100)

    for submission in hot:
      all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = random.choice(colors))

    em.set_image(url = url)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.command()
async def joke(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("cleanjokes")
    all_subs = []
    hot = subreddit.hot(limit = 100)

    for submission in hot:
      all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    text = random_sub.selftext
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = random.choice(colors), description = text)

    await ctx.send(embed = em)


@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("cleanmemes")
    all_subs = []
    hot = subreddit.hot(limit = 100)

    for submission in hot:
       all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = random.choice(colors))

    em.set_image(url = url)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.command()
async def cat(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("catpictures")
    all_subs = []
    hot = subreddit.hot(limit = 100)

    for submission in hot:
       all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = random.choice(colors))

    em.set_image(url = url)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.command()
async def dog(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("dogpictures")
    all_subs = []
    hot = subreddit.hot(limit = 100)

    for submission in hot:
       all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = random.choice(colors))

    em.set_image(url = url)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
  em = discord.Embed(color = random.choice(colors))
  em.add_field(name='General Commands', value='__help__- Displays this message', inline=True)
  await ctx.send(embed = em)


@client.command()
async def server(ctx):
  server = ctx.message.guild

  roles = str(len(server.roles))
  emojis = str(len(server.emojis))
  channels = str(len(server.channels))

  embeded = discord.Embed(title=server.name, description='Server Info', color=random.choice(colors))
  embeded.set_thumbnail(url=server.icon_url)
  embeded.add_field(name="Created on:", value=server.created_at.strftime('%d %B %Y at %H:%M UTC+3'), inline=False)
  embeded.add_field(name="Server ID:", value=server.id, inline=False)
  embeded.add_field(name="Users on server:", value=server.member_count, inline=True)
  embeded.add_field(name="Server owner:", value=server.owner, inline=True)


  embeded.add_field(name="Server Region:", value=server.region, inline=True)
  embeded.add_field(name="Verification Level:", value=server.verification_level, inline=True)

  embeded.add_field(name="Role Count:", value=roles, inline=True)
  embeded.add_field(name="Emoji Count:", value=emojis, inline=True)
  embeded.add_field(name="Channel Count:", value=channels, inline=True)

  await ctx.send(embed=embeded) 


keep_alive()

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

(I am adding this part here because it won't let me revise the question otherwise. It tells me "Looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details". So that is what I am doing, you don't need to read this part.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are locally hosting your bot, then I am pretty much sure that it's your internet. I will show you an example.

**Websocket latency when I host locally:**
[image]

**Websocket latency when I host with Heroku:**
[image]

I experience late response too when I host locally, while with Heroku it's almost instant.

There are some commands which can take much longer than average commands (For example an aiohttp get/post session for uploading an image to Imgur, which takes about 5 seconds when I host locally, but comes almost instantly when I run with Heroku)

Answer (score 3):

This heavily depends on multiple factors.

1. Your code - I cannot help you without seeing your code, but in any case - a few seconds is a lot and better code wont really change that on a small scale
2. Your hardware - Also, this is a small part of your bot's performance, but should be negligible
3. (I think) it is your internet connection. Or maybe Discord's API is having trouble right now.

Of course, there are more factors to it, but it is most likely your internet connection.

Comment: My hardware- I am using a website called __Repl.it__, my internet connection- is pretty good, my code- I am adding that to the question right now

Comment: Mkay there's the code.

Comment: So, your code is not the problem.
I didn't test repl.it myself, but I think it is their fault.
You can get the websocket latency by using 
 https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=latency#discord.Client.latency